# GcmNetworkManager OneoffTask ExecutionWindow needed?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcm-network-manager

I am starting to implement the `GcmNetworkManager` to trigger a sync when the user gets their internet connection back

When looking at the docs for the OneoffTask it says that [setExecutionWindow](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/OneoffTask.Builder.html#public-methods) is mandatory

> Mandatory setter for creating a one-off task

however I only want this to execute when the user has internet and it sounds like it could execute before the user has internet but in the window of `windowStartDelaySeconds` and `windowEndDelaySeconds`.

So does that mean that the network manager could execute the task sometime before `windowEndDelaySeconds` or does that mean that once internet has been restored it will execute in that time?

Comment: The documentation for `setRequiredNetwork()` says "If the specified network is unavailable your task will not be executed until it becomes available." so I don't think it will execute. My question is will the task still execute if they don't get network until after `windowEndDelaySeconds`? You could always set that to a time far enough in the future where it won't matter but I'd still be interested in knowing as I expect it might not execute.

Answer (score 0):

It means the CGM will **try** to execute at some point between the `windowStartDelaySeconds` and `windowEndDelaySeconds` after it has been registered, but also taking in consideration the specified network state.

For example, if you use `.setExecutionWindow(30, 40)` and use `.setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)`, that means the task will be executed at some point between 30 and 40 seconds after being registered **only if** you are connected to a network.

So yes, it could be executed before `windowEndDelaySeconds`, but it also depends on the network state.